# PostgreSQL: Selecting one address from almost but not exactly duplicate rows

Tags: postgresql, join, duplicates

I have a big table that I'm trying to join another table to, however the table has entries such as:

```
---    Name  | Address     | Priority
----------------------------------------
1 | Jane Doe | 123 Baker St |    1
2 | Jane Doe | 345 Clay Dr  |    2
3 | Jeff Boe | 231 Street St|    1  
4 | Karen Al | 4232 Elm St  |    1 
5 | Karen Al | 5632 Pine Ct |    2
```

What I really want to select is one single address per person. The correct address I want is priority 2. However some of the addresses don't have a priority 2, so I can't join only on priority 2.

I've tried the following test query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.ID, LastName, FirstName, MAX(Address), MAX(Address2), City, State, PostalCode, n.Phone
FROM NormalTable n
JOIN Contracts cn ON n.ID = cn.ID
```

Which returns the table that I sketched out above, with the same person/sameID but different addresses.

Is there a way to do this in one query? I can think of maybe doing one `INSERT` statement into my final table where I do all the priority 2 addresses and then ANOTHER `INSERT` statement for IDs that aren't in the table yet, and use the priority 1 address for those. But I'd much prefer if there's a way to do this all in one go where I end up with only the address I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could choice the  address you need joining a subquery for max priority

```
select m.LastName, m.FirstName, m.Address, m.Address2, m.City, m.State, m.PostalCode, m.Phone
from my_table  m
inner join (
  select  LastName, FirstName, max(priority) max_priority
  from  my_table  
  group by  LastName, FirstName
) t on t.LastName = m.LastName
    AND t.FirstName = m.FirstName 
      AND t.max_priority = m.priority
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT (Name), Address, Priority
ORDER BY Priority DESC
```

How this works is that the `DISTINCT (Name)` only returns one row per name. The row returned for each Name is the first row. Which will be the one with the highest priority because of the `ORDER BY`.